# Best workflow on a forked project, which will never merge back into original, but to get updates?

Tags: git, github, git-fork

I'm new to git, and I have a project that I've forked from the original Open Source on Github.

I'm customising the code for my own project, and will never merge back into the original.

I want to benefit from bug fixes and updates on the original.

What approach should I take without having to resolve the same conflicts over and over again? Should I try to avoid modifying the original code modules and import them into new modules? (I'm working in python).

Is there a particular approaching to branching that would help?

Comment: Him I proposed a solution to a similar problem here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69084085/418599 . Please, evaluate it.

Comment: It's not clear to me how that would address my concern that I will need to repeatedly resolve the same conflicts - where I've updated my local code and it differs from the origianl

Comment: This is what [`git rerere`](https://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rerere) is for.